# Is there a way to unsuppress a column in ToolPanel in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need a specific column to show in the ToolPanel in specific cases only.

So in the columnDefs, I've set the suppressToolPanel: true for that column.

However, I can't find a way to unsuppress it, and show that specific column in the ToolPanel in the case I need it.

PS, I've tried column visibility but that doesn't work because even when hiding the column, it still shows in the ToolPanel. The only way to hide it in the ToolPanel is to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`suppressColumnsToolPanel`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/#columns-and-column-groups) can't be a `function` like `editable` property.

> **`suppressColumnsToolPanel`**    Set to true if you do not want this column or group to appear in the Columns Tool Panel.

but you can create own *custom* [toolpanel component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/) and track (and change) whatever you want